# Using Filters in MS-Project Queries using Sharepoint API (PS.js / SP.js)

Tags: sharepoint, office365, ms-project

I'm trying to use the PS.js API to access information in Sharepoint, and I'm struggling to find a way to **practically** use the system.

In this case I'm trying to show upcoming resource allocation. I can easily get my hands on the list of all resources [ProjectContext.get_resources()], and from there the list of each of their assignments to projects/tasks [EnterpriseResource.get_assignments()]. But there are *thousands* of these, and I only want those that are booked **on or after of the current date**.

Is there any way I can create a filter or CAML view of these using the existing SP.js or PS.js, rather than reverting to the REST API?

I'd love if I could just modify the result of 'get_assignments' to add filter options, or add filters as arguments to 'load'. But I can't seem to find any documentation that tells me if it's possible.

Sample Below...

```
function ResourceListArrived(resource)
    //Go through every Resource in the list
    var rEnumerator = Resources.getEnumerator();
    while (rEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var resource = rEnumerator.get_current();        

        $('#message').html('Processing Resource: ' + resource.get_name() + " / " + resource.get_id());
        log('Investigating Resource ' + resource.get_name());
        //Get the assignments for this resource.
        GetResourceAssignments(resource);
    }

    $('#messageblock').fadeOut(500);    
}

function GetResourceAssignments(resource)
{
    var assignments = resource.get_assignments();
    Project.load(assignments, 'Include(Start,Stop)');

    //I'd like to filter THESE results somewhere in the previous 2x lines.

    // Run the request on the server.
    Project.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            TotalRequestsOutstanding--;
            var aEnumerator = assignments.getEnumerator();
            while (aEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var assignment = aEnumerator.get_current();
                log('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Assignment Found On ' + resource.get_name() + " - " + assignment.get_start());
            }           
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to get list of assignments. Error: ' + args.get_message());
        });
}
```